# The output length of upfirdn in MATLAB doesn't match that of the theory

Tags: digital-filters

I have some doubt about the upfirdn built-in function in MATLAB. First I generate the root raised cosine transmit filter as

```
tRRC = rcosdesign(0.25, 20,4,'sqrt');
```

which gives back 81 coefficients. I then pass a signal $\mathbf{x}$ of length $N$ through this filter using the upfirdn as

```
txFilteredSignal = upfirdn(x, tRRC, 4, 1);
```

which according to the documentation should first upsample the input signal $\mathbf{x}$ by a factor of 4, resulting in an oversample signal $\mathbf{s}$ of length $4N$, which is then passed through a filter of length 81. Since the downsampling factor is 1, I expect the filter output to be $4N+80$ but what I get is a signal of length $4N+77$. Why?

Comment: Because the last three samples would be 0 anyway.